# How to covert Fastspeech2 to Onnx with dynamic input and output?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, onnx

How Can I get dynamic input in torch model to onnx model ?
I give input with dynamic_axes, but the output in inference is not dynamic.
My code:

```
    input_names = ['speakers', 'texts', 'src_lens', 'max_src_len']
    output_names = ['output', 'postnet_output', 'p_predictions', 'e_predictions', 'log_d_predictions', 'd_rounded',
                    'src_masks', 'mel_masks', 'src_lens', 'mel_lens']
    dynamic_axes = {
        "texts": {1: "texts_len"},
        "output": {1: "output_len"},
        "postnet_output": {1: "postnet_output_len"},
        "p_predictions": {1: "p_predictions_len"},
        "e_predictions": {1: "e_predictions_len"},
        "log_d_predictions": {1: "log_d_predictions_len"},
        "d_rounded": {1: "d_rounded_len"},
        "src_masks": {1: "src_masks_len"}
    }

    texts_len = 10
    speakers = torch.tensor([0])
    texts = torch.randint(1, 200, (1, texts_len))  
    text_lens = torch.tensor([texts_len])
    max_len = torch.from_numpy(np.array(texts_len)).to(device)
    torch.onnx.export(model, args=(speakers, texts, text_lens, max_len), f="./FastSpeech_2.onnx",
                      input_names=input_names, output_names=output_names, dynamic_axes=dynamic_axes, opset_version=11)
```

In code , I use  `src_lens=10`, it is ok.
But in inference with this onnx model，when I input with `src_lens=50` or other input, I get this error:

```
2022-01-18 16:29:38.644831855 [E:onnxruntime:, sequential_executor.cc:346 Execute] Non-zero status code returned while running Split node. Name:'Split_2888' Status Message: Cannot split using values in 'split' attribute. Axis=0 Input shape={27,256} NumOutputs=10 Num entries in 'split' (must equal number of outputs) was 10 Sum of sizes in 'split' (must equal size of selected axis) was 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torch2onnx_2.py", line 497, in <module>
    onnx_mode_test()
  File "torch2onnx_2.py", line 471, in onnx_mode_test
    ort_outs = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/tts_fffan/lib/python3.6/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 192, in run
    return self._sess.run(output_names, input_feed, run_options)
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.Fail: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Non-zero status code returned while running Split node. Name:'Split_2888' Status Message: Cannot split using values in 'split' attribute. Axis=0 Input shape={27,256} NumOutputs=10 Num entries in 'split' (must equal number of outputs) was 10 Sum of sizes in 'split' (must equal size of selected axis) was 10
```

seems that the input len must be `10` , and it can't be dynamic
Does somebody help me ?
The model of link I use is [Here](https://github.com/ming024/FastSpeech2)